# Visual Basic "Format" function turning Hex values that end with A into a time

Tags: vba

I have inherited some code and am very new to VB.

The code is basically being fed decimal values, these are being converted into the Hex equivalent and (I think) the Format function is being used to make sure only 2 characters (i.e. a byte) are being used in another string.

The problem is this, when the Format function encounters a Hex value that Ends in an 'A', it seems to convert the string into a time format of some sort.

Example:

"4A" converts to 04:00:00

"7A" converts to 07:00:00

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
    Format("4A")
```

In the actual code I'd get a "00", as the function has the following optional additions:

```
    Format("0A","00")
```

I'm assuming the "A" is some special character.

Anybody have an idea around this quirk? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't do it on my side when I look at the output of the example.

Comment: `String.Format("A", "00")` = "A".  `Format("A", "00")` = "00". `String.Format("0A", "00")` = "0A". `Format("0A", "00")` = "00". `VBA` or `VB.Net`?

Comment: Also, see: `Byte.Parse("[String]", NumberStyles.HexNumber)` -- [Byte.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.parse)

Comment: VBA and VB.Net are not the same.  Based on the result of the Format function that you have indicated, it appears that you are using VBA.  I have adjusted the tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is being interpreted as `AM` just as `P` would be `PM` and output `16:00`.

`Format()` is likely not the correct thing to use here, it would only pad as you want it to if the input were a number.

Better to pad after you convert the base:

```
hexa = Hex$(i)
If (i < 16) Then hexa = "0" & hexa
```